how to create table in athena with s3 compressed file the compressed file is sql dump so how can create a table in athena and extract data from s3
i will using a athena for the data extraction from s3

s3 data is sql dump in compressed format bz2 and lz4 but when i create a table in athena using avro with bz2 option and then query is made with that-

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rds-database-backup-archive`.`testing_loop` (`id` int, `type` varchar(255))
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://rds-database-backup-archive/testing-athena/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification' = 'avro',
  'write.compression' = 'BZIP2'
);

it is execute successfully and table is create
but when i execute this command-
 select * from "rds-database-backup-archive"."testing_loop" limit 20;



show this error
HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Not an Avro data file.
This query ran against the ‘rds-database-backup-archive’ database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query ID: b37aaf1b-bdad-4f23-93d4-855bb0b01a22
i want execute query on that location and extract a data from s3 for the data analytics team

It's not an AVRO file, hence the error. How was the SQL Dump file created? Which database engine created it (Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, MariaDB)?

thanks for the response
take dump using this command

mysqldump -u root -h your_rds_endpoint -pYourPassword databasename --set-gtid-purged=OFF tablename > tablename.sql

database engine is mysql
please suggest if any solution of this problem

It appears that you can specifically tell mysqldump to output in CSV format. See: How to export a MySQL database to CSV

hi @JohnRotenstein how to create table and fetch data from s3 and the file in compress form in .gz how to fetch data in my table from s3 which file format use can you share me the all over the process

I have no idea! I was simply trying to assist you with reading the stored dump file via Amazon Athena.
